# Why can't Haskell function return a list

Tags: haskell

What is wrong with that:

```
partin a = [floor a, a-floor a]
```

Error :

```
<interactive>:342:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 16 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: It's talking about printing something, but you don't show how you're trying to print something. Please show the rest of what you're doing.

Comment: Actually when I do  "part a = a - floor a" is also give same error. Code only consist of this functiion

Comment: He just typed `part something` at the GHCi prompt, as per the signature line "In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: `print it`."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't give a complete answer without seeing the full extent of what you're doing, but here's one definite problem that is almost certainly involved. You write

```
partin a = [floor a, a-floor a]
```

The type of `floor` is

```
floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

The type of `(-)` is

```
(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Since you use `a - floor a`, you're forcing the type of `a` to be an instance of *both* the `RealFrac` class *and* the `Integral` class. However, there is no such type in the standard library (and it doesn't make a lot of sense). As a result, GHC certainly will not be able to select the type for you from its very limited collection of defaults. Things might work out a lot better if you use

```
partin a = [fromIntegral (floor a), a - fromIntegral (floor a :: Int)]
```

But note that it doesn't really make much sense to have a *list* here, since you're trying to divide a number into two components of different types. You might be better off with

```
partin a = (floor a, a - fromIntegral (floor a :: Int))
```